# can scroll when mouse is on <HTML> ? (not only this div) - by using jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, scroll, jscrollpane

i try to use this jQuery plugin : http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com

but anyway can i scrolling this **.scroll-pane** when mouse is outside **.scroll-pane** ?

http://jsfiddle.net/UUrkg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [scroll to animate](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to_animate.html) demo. Here's explained how you can trigger the scrollpane to scroll to a specific position.

The only thing you have to do now is to bind the mousescroll event on the other event and trigger it to scroll the scrollpane

Comment: i mean i want to scroll when mouse is outside the DIV, thanks anyway

Comment: that's exactly what you can do with this... it triggers a scroll on the scroll pane

Comment: $(window).scroll(
       
        function()
        {

            api.scrollBy(parseInt(20), parseInt(20));
            return false;
        }
    );


???

Comment: you're right. here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/UUrkg/4/ i'm using here the jquery-mousewheel plugin. good luck